# What does setting CALayer's bounds.origin do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In CALayer's API, 'position' is used for setting the position of the layer.

By my own testing, setting bounds.origin does not do anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bounds.origin` controls where the origin of the layer's coordinate system is, relative to the layer's frame in its superlayer.  Changing it has two visible effects:

1. The position of sublayers of the layer.  For example, when you scroll a `UIScrollView`, the scroll view doesn't change its subview's frames.  It simply changes its `bounds.origin`.  I suggest setting up a toy app with a scroll view and doing `NSLog("scroll view bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollView.bounds));` from a timer or some other trigger to get a sense of what's happening.
2. The origin of the graphics context coordinate system in `drawInContext:`.  Mostly commonly you would see this effect in a view's `drawRect:` method.  Your `CGContext` inside `drawRect:` will have been translated by the `self.bounds.origin`.

You may find it helpful to read about [“View Geometry and Coordinate Systems” in the *View Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5) and [“Layer Objects Define Their Own Geometry” in the *Core Animation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15), although really neither of them have a good discussion of the bounds origin.

Comment: The description you gave is frame.origin. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: `frame.origin` affects the position of the layer in its superlayer.  `bounds.origin` affects the positions of the layer's sublayers and contents.

Comment: You are incorrect about #2. A layer's bounds.origin does not affect the location of its contents, but only the location of its sublayers. For instance, if you assign a CGImage to layer.contents, and then offset bounds.origin, the image will not move.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think what you had originally was much more logical—it's just a shame the system does not work that way! It is especially confusing that `bounds.origin` does NOT affect the on-screen location of an assigned `layer.contents` image, but DOES affect the location of sublayers and drawn graphics. It seems the clearest formulation is: bounds.origin is used to determine where sublayers go and where drawing goes *within the contents*, not *where the contents itself goes*. It has taken me hours to understand this fully!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the bounds rectangle changes the position and size of the content in the coordinate system of the layer itself. Changing the frame (or position) changes the position of the layer in the coordinate system of its super layer. Usually you only want to change the frame, not the bounds.